# What is $25^4 mod 39$ congruent to?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My result is $25^4 \equiv 25 (\textrm{mod}\ 39)$, but [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25%5E4%20mod%2039) simplifies $25^4 \ \textrm{mod}\ 39$ as `1`. How should I interpret this?

I have the following idea:

$25^4 \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\ 39)$

But I don't have an explanation for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $25^2 = 625 = 16\cdot 39 + 1$, we have that $25^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{39}$. Hence $25^4 = (25^2)^2 \equiv (1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{39}$

Answer (score 8):

${\rm mod}\ 3,13\!:\ 25^4\equiv (\color{#c00}{\pm1})^4\equiv 1,\,$ so $\ 3,13\mid 25^4-1\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm lcm}(3,13)=39\mid25^4-1\ \ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $  Answering a question posed in a comment: I decomposed $\,39 = 3\cdot13\,$ because it was clear that this would simplify the computation of $\,25^n \pmod{39}\,$ given that the base $25$ satisifies $\,25\equiv\color{#c00} 1\pmod{3}\,$ and $\,25\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\pmod{13}.\,$ Both $\,\color{#c00}1\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{-1}\,$ are numbers whose powers are trivial to compute, so this greatly simplifies the computation.

Essentially the above employs a special case of the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT). This theorem gives an algebraic method to  "divide and conquer", i.e. to decompose modular arithmetic to arithmetic in *simpler* modular rings, then combine the simpler solutions into a solution to the original problem. When you learn ring theory the innate structure behind CRT will become much clearer, being revealed as an explicit ring isomorphism with a product ring.

Comment: Why did you do a prime factorization of `39`?

Comment: @Morgan I answered your question in a Remark added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated @Bill

Comment: @Morgan This is a *fundamental technique* in number theory and algebra, so the sooner you learn it the easier things will be (e.g.  it simplifies this problem to $\,10$ seconds of trivial mental arithmetic!) $\quad $